# Is it save to replace <input type="submit" > with <button type="submit"> in WordPress search form

Tags: plugins, search, forms

I am asking because of a large userbase and possible conflicts with plugins.

I mean the 2013 theme for example targets the button with `.searchform [type="submit"]` even of it has the `.searchsubmit` class anyway. Maybe because some CSS specificity and something the was declared don't know. But on the first look it makes not much sense to me.

But anyway it's not about themes. How many plug-ins do you guess would fail because the target this not by the class?

I need would prefer the button because It works correctly with the bootstrap `.input-group` stuff and input does not. The Value in not respected for the width its cut off. The text needs to be variable so I cant just set a fixed with on it.

As far as the tag goes I will include the html5 shiv anyway so that should not be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Plugin should never rely on a specific markup for the form. The only part that can be implied is the name of the search field: `s`. I don’t think any good plugin would break if you use a button.

I have written themes without *any* submit button; and nothing was broken.